# Flutter : Error NoSuchMethodError, I don't understand why?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
answerControllers = new Map<String, dynamic>();

List<dynamic> answersToQuestion =
            getAnswersOfQuestion(answers, question["id"]);

        if (!answerControllers.containsKey(question["id"])) {
          answerControllers[question["id"]] = new Map<dynamic, dynamic>();
          if (previousValue == null) {
            for (dynamic answer in answersToQuestion){
              answerControllers[question["id"]][answer["libelle"]]['checked'] = false;
            }
```

And I got this error :

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building
> CreateDemandView(dirty, state:
> _CreateDemandViewState#d56fe): The method '[]=' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: []=("checked", false)

Comment: you are getting null value

Comment: try mapping directly to the class and see if you get a problem

Answer (score 1):

make sure in question["id"] there is a value